# How to exclude disabled tr while selecting "Select All" in Carbon Design DataTable React

Tags: reactjs, datatable, carbon-design-system

I have few rows as disabled. But still that rows are getting selected while selecting "Select All" in Carbon Design Data Table.

[Issue while Select All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6mAe.png)

<TableBatchActions {...batchActionProps}>...In batchActionProps all records are getting stored ( including disabled rows)

Answer (score 0):

Before passing the rows to the DataTable, set `disabled:true` for all the rows that you want to be disabled.